# Javascript Resize Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to resize multiple textareas on my page according to the amount of text in them. The textareas are created in an event handler by replacing the surrounding tags:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.js-post-edit-button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const $form = $(this).parentsUntil(".js-post-update-form").parent();
    const $h5 = $form.find(".post-title");
    const $p = $form.find(".post-content");
    $h5.replaceWith($("<textarea/>", {
        "name": "post_edit[title]",
        "class": "form-control js-textarea-content",
        "id": "js-textarea-title",
        "style": "margin-bottom: 20px;",
        "text": $h5.text().replace("\n", "").replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ").trim(),
    }));
    $p.replaceWith($("<textarea/>", {
        "name": "post_edit[description]",
        "class": "form-control js-textarea-content",
        "id": "js-textarea-description",
        "style": "margin-bottom: 20px;",
        "text": $p.text().replace("\n", "").replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ").trim(),
    }));
    resizeTextarea();
});

function resizeTextarea () {
    const textarea = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control js-textarea-content");
    textarea.style.height = 'auto';
    textarea.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
}
```

When I click on the edit button (js-post-edit-button), I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error please?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` will return a collection of elements so you need to specify which element you wish to target. For example - target the first element in the collection **via** index `document.getElementsByClassName("form-control js-textarea-content")[0];` Maybe if you could create a working snippet or maybe a [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/) to work with it might be easier to help you.

Comment: you catch the textarea on the click event so no need to get the textarea again in the function .. you can reference `this` to the function ..try to remove the `const textarea=` line then use `this.style`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NewToJS pretty much already gave you the answer. I'll try to add some extra nuance.

**Why you code doesn't work**

According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) `getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection (a list of elements).

- You are trying to access a property (height) from another property (style) of this collection. Because the property 'style' does not exist on the HTMLCollection this will return `undefined`.
- Now you are trying to change the 'height' property on this.

That should explain why you get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined
```

**Alternative approach**

I would just change the function to accept an element as parameter.

```
function resizeTextarea ( textarea ) {
    textarea.style.height = 'auto';
    textarea.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
}
```

You could also use a more OOP approach and add a new method to `HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype`. Whatever you fancy I suppose.

**Now you can get the element any way you want**

- I would ***not recommend*** using `getElementsByClassName()[0]`. It probably works most of the time but can lead to unexpected scenarios when that class exists multiple times on a page.
- Better would be `document.getElementById()` if you are 100% sure the element will only appear once on a page.
- You could use the reference to the element when you generate it in javascript.

Comment: Thanks RMo, I changed the function to accept a textarea element as a parameter, however I still get the same error. I am calling like this after the replaceWith():

    const titleTextarea = $form.find('.js-textarea-content');
    resizeTextarea(titleTextarea);

Comment: You probably aren't using the right input ( an element ). This could very well be because you are using a jQuery selector result, which isn't the same as an element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you absolutely want to code it by yourself, for learning or another reason :-)

Anyway, if you're opened to the idea to use an existing js plugin, I can suggest you this excellent one : http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

With a single line of code like this `autosize($('textarea'))` it will work immediately...

Here is a [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/rgahL3xm/)

```js
$('#autosize').autosize();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autosize.js/1.18.4/jquery.autosize.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="autosize" style="width:200px;">
First
Second
Third</textarea>
```

Comment: Maybe adding this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/rgahL3xm/) into your question might be of some help or maybe use that to create a working snipped.

Comment: You're right :-) I could have done this. That's why I gave him a direct link to the demo and not the github repo...

Comment: Links are helpful but some expire so creating a working example is always a good idea. I will add a working snipped of my demo into your answer if you are happy for me to do that?

Comment: You're right again, I note this for my next answers... As Jack Moore is a very well known guy, I thought it was a good idea to link to his website...  Yes you can add the working snippet, thanks a lot!